# Is it possible to monitor a Java process that experienced an OOM error?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have a java process running as a windows service using a jsl.
For some reason it experienced an outofmemory error. 
The process is still running and I wonder, before I stopping the service, if there is a way to analyze why the OOM occurred?

Thanks in advance.
Guy

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot unwind the state in the JVM to the moment the OOME happened. You can can take a heapdump for analysis using [`jmap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html). That should give you a good idea what is taking most of the memory *now*.

I would also **strongly** recommend you to run the process with the [+XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html#gbzrr) parameter. This will trigger an automated heapdump when the application finds an OOM error. In my opnion, all java apps should be started with this option, as otherwise it's impossible to investigate OOM Errors, and it doesn't add any overhead on an app (as long as there are no OOM errors).